# adding claims accesstoken validation identityserver3

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, identityserver3

I'm using Idsrv3 as my Authentication provider.  My Api is validating the token and creating the correct principal etc, just as it should.  Now I wish to add **application specific** claims to the principal after the validation is done and the principal is created but before anything else in the WebApi pipeline is executed.

I could write my own DelegatingHandler I suppose to handle this, but is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put middleware in the pipeline after the Bearer token authentication middleware, but before your web api framework. In this custom middleware you can inspect the incoming claims, and change or replace them with whatever else you want.

Comment: still might be nice to have a plugin point from the IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions...